# i want to count specific IDs from my tables

Tags: php, mysql, count

i have this code

```
<?php 
    $votes_query=mysql_query("select * from votes where CandidateID='$id'");
    $vote_count=mysql_num_rows($votes_query);
    echo $vote_count;
?>
```

which fetches individual **ID**s from my `votes` table.

I need a code which can help fetch the sum of specific **ID**s.

Lets say, I have `ID-205` and `ID-209` in my table.

Comment: `group by CandidateID`.

Comment: you should stop using `mysql_` function. for more info see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: `select CandidateID, count(*) from votes where CandidateID IN (?,?..) group by CandidateID `

Comment: wow ..thanks for the very fast response...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ids = array('205','209');

$votes_query=mysql_query("select * from votes where CandidateID IN($ids) ");
$vote_count=mysql_num_rows($votes_query);
echo $vote_count;
?>
```

Put all ID's in an array & Use IN Clause of mysql.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $ids = array('205','209');

    $sql  "SELECT SUM(field_score) AS vote_score FROM votes WHERE CandidateID IN ($ids)";

    $vote_score = mysql_query($sql);
    echo $vote_score;    
?>
```